# Kotlin: platform declaration clash: same JVM signature

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to implement an abstract class in kotlin which extends a `MultiValuedMap`, when I was trying to override `keySet()` method, I got the error

```
platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (keySet()Ljava/util/Set;)
```

My code:

```
abstract class ConfigProperties<K, V>(delegate: Map<K, V>?): MultivaluedMap<String, String> {

  protected val delegate: Map<K, V>

  init {
      if (delegate == null) {
          throw NullPointerException("Config properties delegate must not be null.")
      }
      this.delegate = delegate
  }

  abstract fun putCacheProperty(key: Parameter, value: Any)

  abstract fun getCacheProperty(key: Parameter): Any

  protected val UNSUPPORTED_MESSAGE = "ConfigProperties is immutable."


  override fun keySet(): Set<String> {
      return delegate.keys
  }
```

}

Any hint to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem begins with `MultivaluedMap<String,String>`

```
abstract class ConfigProperties<K, V>(delegate: Map<K, V>?):
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> { ... }
```

Overlook the `String` type parameter for the moment.  `MultivaluedMap<K,V>` is an interface that has the `Map<K,List<V>>` super interface.  But in your code, you have a `delegate` of type `Map<K,V>`.  You try to override a the `setKey` member of the `Map<K,List<V>>` super interface by returning `delegate.keys` which is not the same as `Map<K,List<V>>.keys` (i.e., whose member you are overriding).

So, you can try the following...

```
abstract class ConfigProperties<K, V>(delegate: Map<K, V>?):
        MultivaluedMap<K, V> {
    protected val delegate: Map<K, List<V>>
    init {
        if (delegate == null) {
            throw NullPointerException("Config properties delegate must not be null.")
        }
        this.delegate = delegate
    }
    abstract fun putCacheProperty(key: Parameter, value: Any)
    abstract fun getCacheProperty(key: Parameter): Any
    protected val UNSUPPORTED_MESSAGE = "ConfigProperties is immutable."
    override fun keySet(): Set<K> {
        return delegate.keys
    }
}
```

As for the `String` type parameter, did you mean to use `K,V`?  Whatever you meant, you will need to make the consistent.